# Ethernet connection not working- "Ethernet doesn't have a valid IP configuration" Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, router, ethernet

I recently bought an ethernet to USB adapter as it is now a job requirement for me to have an ethernet connection and my laptop doesn't have one natively. I cannot for the life of me figure out the problem. Maybe it's something to do with the router?

The problem as described by the network troubleshooter:
"Ethernet 4" doesn't have a valid IP configuration

It is getting a local IP as can be seen here:

```
 Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek USB GbE Family Controller #2  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-4C-68-D6-35  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::48f1:6bbb:c6c2:ff40%18(Preferred)  
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.255.64(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :  
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335601740  
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-43-E0-A4-9C-B6-D0-D4-5E-51  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8  
                                       8.8.4.4  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

So if I am understanding correctly this -due to the IP address and no gateway address- is a communication problem between my router and computer, right?

Things I tried:

1)
Admin command promt:
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset

reboot

2)
Disable and enable NIC in Network Connections
reboot

3)
Ensured that IP Address and DNS Address are set to automatic

4) 
Uninstalled device from Device Manager
Updated drivers from Device Manager

5) 
Manually set IP Adress settings to: 
IP Address: 192.168.1.14
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS Server: 8.8.4.4

6)
Admin command prompt:
ipconfig/flushdns
nbtstat -R
nbtstat -RR
netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
netsh winsock reset

7)
Turned off computer
Turned off router for 30 seconds
Restarted router
Turned on computer

Is there anything that might indicate the problem is some configuration or something like this with my computer? I do have direct access to the router but I am not the owner and doubt I would be allowed to update the firmware or something like that. Thanks all for your help, any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your descriptions mentions #2, do you have two adapters or maybe have used different usb ports? Also there is no gateway defined. Your IPv4 address is of apipa type. Did you issue an `ipconfiog /All` to see all adpters? Maybe your Wlan configuration interferes?

Comment: In the future I'd look into buying an AX88179-based adapter instead...

Comment: I do not have two adapters and have only used the adapter on one port. Why it says #2 I have no clue. I did use ipconfig /all to see all adapters, I am confident this is the correct one, especially since it's my only LAN option under Network Connections.  
  
@grawity How is an adapter with that chip better? 

Thanks